# Sorting Tableview by distance, Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, tableview, distance

i am pretty new at coding and currently stuck, i have not been able to find a working solution, so here is my problem, and hopefully someone here is able to help me.

What i am trying to achieve is to sort my data by distance to the nearest restaurant. I can calculate the distance and display it in my list view, but unfortunately i have not been able to figure out how to sort the list by distance. I am assuming it is due to me calculating the distance and then returning the configured cells. (I have been able to sort the restaurant by name, hours, etc.)

I pull my restaurantdata from firebase in my viewdidload, add it to an array, and the reload my tableview.

Below is the code where i calculate distance. 
Any help is greatly appreciated, and let me know if i need to post more info or code.

- Nik

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "restaurantCell", for: indexPath) as? RestaurantCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
      cell.selectionStyle = .none
      let restaurantInfo = restaurantDataArray[indexPath.row]

      let coordinate0 = CLLocation(latitude: RestaurationerVC.lat, longitude: RestaurationerVC.lon)
      let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: restaurantInfo.latitude, longitude: restaurantInfo.longitude)
      let mulitplier = pow(10.0, 1.0)
      let distanceInKm = (coordinate0.distance(from: coordinate1)) / 1000
      let distanceRounded = round(distanceInKm * mulitplier) / mulitplier

      cell.configureCell(title: restaurantInfo.title!, restaurantImg: restaurantInfo.subtitle!, distance: "\(distanceRounded) Km", hours: restaurantInfo.hours, restaurantType: restaurantInfo.restaurantType, photo: restaurantInfo.photo)

      return cell
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you sort your array that you get from Firebase and then reload the data in the tableView. It would be very inefficient to try sort the tableview itself. When you say you calculate the distance in just before returning the cell that could be changed to calculate it in yuor datamodel. Try creating a struct that will represent the data for one cell(let's call it struct Restaurant). That can have variables for all your calculated data. Then you can put all of them in restaurants = Restaurant and you can implement sorting by distance,  and then use this array in your tableview cellforrowat indexpath function.